# Put two JavaScript functions together for one button? (JavaScript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, function

I have 2 separate functions working that use 2 different buttons, however I want to put them together for so that both functions are triggered simultaneously under one button.

I have a user registration form, and I have one function that sends the data into the database, and the other function checks if the username is existing or not.

What I need is for when the user submits the form, the form should not be submitted if the username already exists, thus an alert should appear saying for example "username taken, please try another". Nevertheless, if username has not been taken, then submit the form.

Can someone shed some light on how I can go about this and put both these functions together for the same button?

Register Function -

```
   function registerUser() {
       var Username = document.getElementById("txtusername").value;
       var Firstname = document.getElementById("txtfirstname").value;
       var Lastname = document.getElementById("txtlastname").value;
       var Email = document.getElementById("txtemail").value;
       var Password = document.getElementById("txtpassword").value;
       var Confirmpass = document.getElementById("passwordconfirm").value;

         db = window.openDatabase("SoccerEarth", "2.0", "SoccerEarthDB", 2*1024*1024);
         db.transaction(function(tx) {
          NewUser(tx, Username, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password, Confirmpass);
          }, errorRegistration, successRegistration);
          }

          function NewUser(tx, Username, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Password, Confirmpass) {
          var _Query = ("INSERT INTO SoccerEarth(UserName, FirstName, LastName, Email, Password, CPass) values ('"+ Username +"','"+ Firstname +"','"+ Lastname +"','"+ Email +"', '"+ Password +"', '"+ Confirmpass +"')");
           alert(_Query);
           tx.executeSql(_Query);
           }
           function errorRegistration(error) {
        navigator.notification.alert(error, null, "Got an error mate", "cool");
            }
           function successRegistration() {
           navigator.notification.alert("User data has been registered", null, "Information", "ok");
             $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", "#page4" );
         }
```

Check username in database function-

```
 function CheckUser()
          {
         db = window.openDatabase("SoccerEarth", "2.0", "SoccerEarthDB", 2*1024*1024);
         db.transaction(UserDB, errorCB);
         }

         function UserDB(tx)
         {
         alert("user check");
            var User = document.getElementById("txtusername").value;
          tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM SoccerEarth WHERE UserName='" + User + "'", [], renderUser);

          }
            function renderUser(tx,results) {
            if (results.rows.length > 0) {
             navigator.notification.alert("Username is taken, please try again.");
              }
              else
              {
             navigator.notification.alert("Username available!");
              }
```

HTML -

```
<form id="form1" data-ajax="false">
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="txtusername" data-theme="d">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtusername" name="txtusername" maxlength="12"  placeholder="Enter Username"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="txtfirstname" data-theme="d">First Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtfirstname" name="txtfirstname" placeholder="Enter First Name"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="txtlastname" data-theme="d">Last Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtlastname" name="txtlastname" placeholder="Enter Last Name"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="txtemail" data-theme="d">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="txtemail" name="txtemail" placeholder="Enter Enter Email"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="txtpassword" data-theme="d">Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtpassword" name="txtpassword" maxlength="12" placeholder="Enter Password"/>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontainer">
            <label for="passwordconfirm" data-theme="d">Confirm Password:</label>
            <input type="text" id="passwordconfirm" name="passwordconfirm" maxlength="12"   placeholder="Confirm password"/>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register User">
```

Input Validations (JQUERY) -

```
 $('#form1').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}).validate({
    rules: {
        txtusername: {
            required: true
        },
        txtfirstname: {
            required: true
        },
        txtemail: {
            required: true
        },
        txtpassword: {
            required: true
        },
        passwordconfirm: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        txtusername: {
            required: "Please enter your Username."
        },
        txtfirstname: {
            required: "Please enter your First Name."
        },
        txtemail: {
            required: "Please enter your Email."
        },
        txtpassword: {
            required: "Please enter your Password."
        },
        passwordconfirm: {
            required: "Please enter your password again."
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        error.appendTo(element.parent().prev());
    },
    submitHandler: function (form, user) {

        registerUser(form);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You should call fn registerUser in the else part of CheckUser i.e instead of navigator.notification.alert("Username available!").. fn ChekUser should be called on the button click..may need some changes further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see in your code that you check if the username is available, so you can use the event onchange

```
<input type="text" onchange="CheckUser()" id="txtusername" name="txtusername" maxlength="12"  placeholder="Enter Username"/>
```

so when the user write some your function CheckUser() is activated, after that you can use normally , inside of

```
if (results.rows.length > 0) {
    navigator.notification.alert("Username is taken, please try again.");
} else {
     //add event click only if is available your username
     navigator.notification.alert("Username available!");
     element = document.getElementById("btnSend");
     element.addEventListener("click", registerUser())
}
```

and write your input submit with this id btnSend

```
<input id="btnSend" type="submit" value="Register User">
```

So in this way you validate if the username is available only in this case you add RegisterUser() for your submit

last but not least be more careful because you wrote code in your JS (Query for DB) and this can be affecty your security

Comment: I really like this method, however how can I prevent a user still going on to submit the form even if the username has been taken?

Comment: Form was still submitted again. I have updated my question to show the jquery i use to validate the input fields and at the end of the code it also fires the registerUser function. Is this causing the conflict?

Comment: Ok, so I have changed the jquery code to trigger the checkuser function instead. Good news, this is now not allowing the form to be submitted until a new username is entered, only issue now is that as soon as a user goes back to change the username and it is valid the form submits automatically without allowing the user to check through the form and manually submit. Do you see where this issue could lie? (Appreciate all your help!!)

Comment: hahahah great good job bro!!! please vote my answer hahahaha have a good code this week

Comment: I removed the onchange and it is now all working with your above code. Voted up and made the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create new function which call this 2 functions

```
function newfunction()
{
  // you need to return true/false from check user function
  if(CheckUser())
  {
    registerUser();
  }
}
```

and call this on **onclick**

```
<input type="submit" value="Register User" onclick="newfunction()">
```

Comment: I think this requires CheckUser to return false otherwise registerUser will also be executed.

Comment: It will be better to do the validation on event onsubmit. It makes sure the validation is performed even when user presses enter for submitting the form.

Comment: Where would I return false on the checkuser function? Because this function did work however the form was also submitted.

Comment: I put the return false after the if "username is taken", however this did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use a onsubmit event to handle the registration

```
<form id="form1" data-ajax="false" onsubmit="doSubmit();">
```

and javascript function will look like

```
function doSubmit(){
   // check if the user exists. Return a boolean value to return the status
   var userExists = checkUser();

   // if user exists, return false to protect form from submitting.
   if(userExists){
      return false;
   }

   // if user does not exists, register the user
   registerUser();
}
```